# Yii2 redirect to previous page after update review

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a page comp/computer?id=15

- it has reviews that can be edited through link
  http://comp/computer/update?id=3 = with FORM and submit button
- how to go back after sumbit

```js
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = new ReviewForm();
        $comment = Review::findOne($id);

        if ($model->load($this->request->post())) {

            $comment->text = $model->text;
            if ($comment->save(false)) {

                return $this->redirect(["?id=15"], );  ????????????
            }
        
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
                'success',
                'Success'
            );
        }

        $model->setAttributes($comment->getAttributes(['name', 'email', 'text']));
        return $this->render('update', compact('model'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use referrer.

`return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer)`

If it has no referrer or link open directly then you should either pass computer_id as param or you must have computer_id as foreign key in your review table.

Let say you have relationship with review and computer table. then you can use like this.

`$compId = $comment->computer_id; // or 15 or you can paas param here`

`return $this->redirect(["comp/computer", "id"=> $compId]);`

if `comp` is your hostname then

`return $this->redirect(["computer", "id"=> $compId]);`

its should be `controller/action`

`return $this->redirect(["controllerId/actionId", "id"=> $compId]);`

Send via mobile, sorry for typos.

Comment: I did it, dont work/  after update text and click sumbit i stay on http://comp/computer/update?id=3

Comment: can you tell me if you review model have any relation with computer table?

Comment: probably not
i write    $computers = $comment->id;
    return $this->redirect(['computer/', "id"=> $computers]);  
And after sumbit gets http://comp/computer?id=5  = need http://comp/computer?id=15

Comment: what is computer_id  (Property accessed via magic method )

Comment: computer_id js just example for your relational property.

Comment: how you will get 15 number where you want to send the user. will it always be 15 or will it comes from somewhere?

Comment: will it comes from somewhere

Comment: sorry for wasting time , 10 days learns yii/   I don't understand how I can get computer_id 
https://github.com/faradeifrontend/domains/tree/master/comp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244091/discussion-between-fahad-ali-and-faradei).